# Windows Server 2008 TS CAL Licensing

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have recently started a job with a local furniture retailer that has a fairly small server farm.  I have never worked with CAL's before, so this is all new to me.
Here is the scenario:
All of our employees rdp in to a 2008 R2 server that hosts the company's sales application.  The sales people do so via iPads and the rest through their desktops.
The event log on that server is full of 4105 TerminalServices-Licensing warnings.  I mean full.  I have verified the server is a member of the correct groups and the right services are running.  Now, here is what I find odd, when I go to the RD Session Host Configuration-Licensing Diagnosis it shows there are 25 CALS installed and 25 available.  Yet I know there are at least 20 people rdp'd in.  All of those people are in the event log.  i.e "The Remote Desktop license server cannot update the license attributes for user "o**floor02" in the Active Directory Domain "*******.net". 
Am I over thinking this?  Or is there really something out of whack?
Thanks in advance for your assistance!
Stephanie

Comment: Something obviously is out of whack - you have licenses that are not used (according to info) and license warnings about not enough licenses. Something does not line up and thus the licenses are never assigned.

Comment: `I have verified the server is a member of the correct groups` - What groups, specifically? Which server is hosting the RDS License Server role? Is the RDS License server a Domain Controller?

Comment: It is a member of Terminal Server License Server.  The server that hosts the software is the hosting the license server role and it is not a DC.  So the server that is being remoted in to and showing all of the errors is the license server.

Answer (score 0):

When an account is created, permissions to update those attributes are stamped directly on the user account.  The permissions are not inherited.  Pre-existing accounts may not have those access control entries to grant permission.

Inspect the permissions granted to the Terminal Server License Servers group on one of the accounts it is complaining about in the logs.

If they are not present, a quick fix would be to grant the Terminal Server License Servers group write permission for the required attributes at the top-level of the domain, and apply to Descendant Child Objects.

Comment: Thank you Greg Askew!  I made that change and will let you know.  I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to have worked.  The errors are still coming in and the licenses still show as available.  The users are able to connect but the mess is driving me nuts.